# Membase? How does this work?

Tags: membase, spymemcached

When I add an IP address and make connection, does the client gets All server's available IP addresses?

Or does client need to know at least 2 IP addresses for when one of them goes down?

This is the code I've been testing with (JAVA)

```
List addrList = new ArrayList();
 addrList.add("192.168.20.105:11211");
 addrList.add("192.168.20.106:11211");
 addrList.add("192.168.20.101:11211");

try {

List addr = AddrUtil.getAddresses(addrList);
 mbsClnt = new MemcachedClient (new BinaryConnectionFactory() , addr);
```

If I've added only one IP address, and while i was doing the gets and sets operation and the server goes down.
 Will the client be able to connect to other available servers?
 because if I add an observer and see the available servers, i dont see any (if i add only one server in the list)
 Does this mean I have to add as many IP addresses as possible to avoid connection failures?

Another question is that , I can see that when i add the IP address, I have to put in PORT number which is linked to specific vBucket. Does it make any overflow from making all the clients watching a same vbucket? If so, how am I supposed to balance the Clients to watch different vBuckets?

Sorry if My English isn't really getting to you T^T.

Any kind of advices or answers will be very appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that your using the memcached constructors in MemcachedClient. If you are on 2.7.x or lower you want to use the constructor that takes a list of URI's, a bucket name, and a password. That constructor will connect to a Membase/Couchbase node and get a list of all servers in the cluster. Then if you rebalance or failover nodes Spymemcached will do the right thing and connect to new nodes or drop connections to nodes leaving the cluster.

In Spymemcached 2.8.x and later we actually removed this functionality and placed it into a new project called Couchbase Client. In that project you will find only the constructor I mentioned above. This should make it more obvious for what you should do. Couchbase Client 1.0.1 currently doesn't have support for views, but that will be added in the next release. Also Couchbase Client is compatible with all versions of Membase.

One other thing. You only need to provide one URI in order to get a list of all nodes in the cluster, but it is recommended that you add as many URI's as you have servers in the cluster. The reason for this is that if the node you specify in the URI goes down you will lose connection to the cluster since you won't be able to get cluster updates. If you specify more than one URI then Spymemcached/Couchbase Client will try to connect to the next node in the list of URI's.

Comment: Well I had to use Membase.. not couchbase.. for the start
I've added an Observer to the code and tried seeing getAvailableServers. However, if I add only one URI, it only shows one available servers. So I am still confused about client getting a list of all servers in the cluster. Is there any way I can check this?
Also, I've seen different kinds of deployments of Membase. I am having confusion on "moxi on Client Side." I kind of don't get this definition... will be great if I can see any examples or how it works.
THX :D

Comment: Let move this discussion to the Couchbase forum since I don;t think stackoverflow works well for this kind of discussion.
http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/wondering-how-couchbase-works-situation

Comment: hmm is it appropriate though? I was wondering the compatibility between couchbase and membase. are they fully exact? including apis? Is the only difference between those two are the DB?

Comment: Couchbase 1.8 is Membase rebranded. Couchbase 2.0 will contain a different persistence layer and have the ability to do queries through views. Everything you can do in Couchbase 1.8 you can do in 2.0. The java sdk, couchbase client 1.0.1, is made specifically for Couchbase 1.8 and will also work with Membase 1.6 and 1.7. All of the user level api's in couchbase client 1.0.1 will remain the same for the 2.0 release. We will however add new api's to the client for views.